# Setting the root password vs. sudo -i

Tags: security, sudo, password, root, su

Should one always set a root password, or is `sudo -i`  acceptable? Two problems is in [reading other posts (maybe junk I realize)](http://www.ubuntux.org/how-to-change-the-root-password-in-ubuntu):

1. `sudo -i` eliminates the need for a password. Isn't that a problem for security reasons?
2. there are conflicting views on whether to change the password from its original hash value:

> By default the root user is setup with a random hash during the install of Ubuntu

If one should use the original hash value, I have no idea what mine is. How do I retrieve it?

Lastly, does the answer change if multiple people will be using the root account (password sharing best practices)?

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your mention of hash value.

Comment: You should probably post the comments that stand out the most on that page instead of linking to external content that may or may not be there in the future.

Comment: @psusi sorry about that, just added the relevant quotation

Answer (score 7):

The reason `sudo` is better than having a root password and using `su` in a multi admin environment is because with `su`, every admin has to know the root password, so if you ever want to revoke an admin's access, you have to change the password, and tell all of the other admins.  With `sudo` you just remove them from the admin group.

`sudo` also offers more fine grained control, because you can configure it to allow people to run only a specific set of commands as root.  For instance, you can allow helpdesk people to run `passwd` to reset users's passwords, without giving them full root access.

The quote you mention is actually wrong.  Ubuntu *locks* the root account by default, so it has *no* password, but can not be logged in as.  It also has a patched `sulogin` so that if the listed value in /etc/shadow is a bare "!" character ( the default, locked, no password value ), then single user/recovery mode will not prompt you for a root password to login.

Comment: thanks, so what you're saying is using `sudo i` is an ok practice? I guess i'm confused b/c than anyone that accesses the machine can just type `sudo i` and do what they want. Is that fear not warranted?

Comment: @timpeterson only users in the admin group can use sudo.

Comment: @Random832 how is the admin group defined? I obviously am part of it but confess I have no idea what I did during the setup which made me an admin.

Comment: @timpeterson, `sudo` is configured via `/etc/sudoers`, and the installer puts the initial user it prompts you to create in the admin group automatically.  You should read the `sudo` man page for details.

Comment: @psusi to get back to your answer, what you're saying is `sudo i` is an ok practice?

Comment: @timpeterson, yes.. if you want a root shell instead of just prefixing an individual command with `sudo`, then `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` is the way to go.  The difference between the two is that `-s` preserves your environment so for instance, `~` still refers to YOUR home directory, instead of root's.  This is usually the preferred behavior.  The `su` equivalent to this difference is `su` vs `su -`.

Comment: Another point is that `sudo(1)` logs each user's actions. Also, it there is only one user, there is no way to crack root's password, i.e., that particular attack surface is reduced by half.